# Electron location.pathname is incorrect on initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, electron-builder

At the moment I'm building an Electron application which uses React (and the React Router).

When I open my packaged application (packaged with [Electron Builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)) initially no route is matched. So I logged the `location.pathname` which should be `/` on the initial load. Instead I get the entire path of where my `index.html` is placed (`blabla/dist/mac/ds-video-wall.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/index.html`).

I fixed this (temporary) by added the following code:

```
componentWillMount() {
  // Electron 'bugfix', feels dirty
  if (this.props.location.pathname !== '/') {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
}
```

After this redirect I can start using the navigation and everything works fine from there. Every time I change routes I log the `location.pathname` and it's always correct. So this problem only occurs on initial load.

However, I don't like my solution and I think this should be solved differently. Any ideas on how I can correct the wrong initial value of `location.pathname`?

Comment: how are you loading the BrowserWindow from the main process?

Answer (score 2):

This actually was quite easy to fix: I just needed to use the [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) instead of the [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter).

After that everything worked properly and I could remove my 'bugfix'.